# Make a div top border width increase to bottom with color

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me from this following

[image]

to this following

[image]

I am unable to make this `red` border with CSS. Help is appreciated. Ignore the div width. Only thing I need help is the `red` background section. My code till now:

```css
.location-dtls {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;

    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 15%;
    max-width: 15%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    border-width: 0.001rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-color: #e4e2e2;
  }
```

```html
<div class="location-dtls">
  <div>Location 5</div>
  <div>Location 5 FN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pesudo elements to do this:

```css
.location-dtls {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;

    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 15%;
    max-width: 15%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    border-width: 0.001rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-color: #e4e2e2;

}
 
.location-dtls::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="location-dtls">
  <div>Location 5</div>
  <div>Location 5 FN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image you pasted has one additional rectangle, it seems. Do you only need the top section in red color, something like the following? You can achieve it by customizing the `border-top-width` and `border-top-color` rules.

```css
.location-dtls {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;

    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 15%;
    max-width: 15%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    border-width: 0.001rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-color: #e4e2e2;
    border-top-width: 1.5rem;
    border-top-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="location-dtls">
  <div>Location 5</div>
  <div>Location 5 FN</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if the `red` div section have small border radius like in image. That would be helpful.

Comment: you can adjust it accordingly. Tweak the `border-top-width` rule in the CSS.

Comment: Okay, let me check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One thing though. Can you please tell me how to solve the gap which is generated if I apply your code. Specifically `border-top-color: red;`. Link: https://imgur.com/a/3l99UAv

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution for this will be

```css
.wrapper{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:.3em;
}

p{
  margin:0;
}

.content{
  padding:.3em 1em;
}

.red{
  width:100%;
  height:1em;
  border-radius:.3em;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="content">
     <p>Location 5</p>
     <p>Location 5 FN</p>
  </div>
</div>
```